# How do I get the value of my pref_name in SharedPreferences inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have been trying to fetch a the value of a key from SharedPreferences as a string so that I can modify the data in the layout connected to the fragment.

Here is my code of OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

private TextView mText;

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("EID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     String value = prefs.getString("EID", "0");

    mText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mText.setText(value);
 return view;

  }
}
```

The app said that it has stopped when it opens. I am calling the fragment from Main activity.

What the studio says :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.dell.tab2, PID: 3857
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.tab2/com.example.dell.tab2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:164)
                  at com.example.dell.tab2.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:31)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Stacktrace says its your `MainActivity` where the crash is. You're calling `getSharedPreferences()` too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this value from your Activity if you can't get it in Fragment. Call in fragment:

```
String value = ((YourActivityName)getActivity()).getValuePreference();
```

and add method in your Activity:

```
public String getValuePreference(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString("EID", "0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add below code in fragment

```
  Context context;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

In `onCreateView` replace `getActivity()` with `context`

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("EID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String value = prefs.getString("EID", "0");
```